# CMake in QtCreator 4.3 shows many automatic targets, how to remove/hide them?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, ctest

I just switched to the last version of QtCreator (4.3.1) and the project explorer now shows many targets like *ContinuousBuild, ContinuousConfigure, NightlyBuild, ExperimentalCoverage* etc.

How can I remove all of these (or at least hide them) ?
I don't even know where this is generated in CMake.

Seems to be related to this question [Hide automatically generated CTest targets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44949354/6165833) except that I am not using CLion.

Comment: Similar question for Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006143/2799037

Comment: Just to note that I've logged a feature request for CMake to provide a way to prevent the creation of these targets:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21730

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using somewhere:

```
include(CTest)
```

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html):

> Configure a project for testing with CTest/CDash

All those targets are pulled in by the combination of the two, `CTest` **and** `CDash` (almost all of them are due to the latter actually).
If you don't know why they are there and for what they can be used, probably you are using the wrong command.

If all what you want is to use only `CTest`, add tests with `add_test` and run them with `make test`, replace the line above with this one:

```
enable_testing()
```

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) is quite clear indeed:

> Enable testing for current directory and below.

Clean up the build directory and run `cmake` from scratch from within `QtCreator`. All the targets you mentioned should disappear.

---

I had exactly the same problem in a project of mine when I updated `QtCreator` a couple of months ago. You can see in the history of the project the [commit](https://github.com/skypjack/uvw/commit/9ed86d9deebf52f915159f1b7df74245be884c8f#diff-af3b638bc2a3e6c650974192a53c7291) that solved the issue. Pretty short indeed.